Lightning Web Security breaks LWC code
I have custom LWC that send array data from LWC to apex controller.
When LWS is turned OFF everything goes fine, but when LWS is turned ON the code stop at the line where call the apex controller.

let listAPRItem = [];

for(let i=0; i<this.digitalAPR.length; i++){
    listAPRItem.push(this.digitalAPR[i]);

    //I added this line just to debug what's inside the variable
    //But unfortunatelly the code stop here because of an error but it's shows nothing even used try catch
    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.digitalAPR[i])));

    //This code is not executed
    console.log('test');
}

//If the debug above removed, the code will stop execute in here
handleCreateBusinessCase({recordId: this.recordId, jsonData: JSON.stringify(recordObj), untypedListAPR: this.digitalAPR, untypedListFiles: listFile, isDraft: isDraft})
.then(result => {
    //This code till end will not executed
    console.log('handleCreateBusinessCase success');
    console.log(result);

    this.recordId = result;

    if(isDraft){
        this.isLoading = false;

        if(this.editMode || this.fullPermission){
            this.showToast('Success', 'Business Case saved successfully.', 'success', 'dismissable');
        }
        else{
            this.showToast('Success', 'Business Case saved as draft successfully.', 'success', 'dismissable');
            return;
        }
    }
    else{
        this.showToast('Success', 'Business Case submitted successfully.', 'success', 'dismissable');
    }

    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: result,
            actionName: 'view',
        },
    });
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log('handleCreateBusinessCase error');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));

    this.isLoading = false;
    this.showToast('Error', error.body.message, 'error', 'dismissable');
});

this.digitalAPR initialized as array and use @track.
When LWS is turned ON, the code is stop at line 933, even thought I removed line 933 the code will still stop and line 936.
But when LWS is turned OFF, everything run smoothly, at line 933 it shows the data.
Any idea ?
=== Updated and resolved ===
I have added new variable listAPRItem cloned from digitalAPR by looping it and send listAPRItem to apex instead of the digitalAPR.
And works perfectly.
let listAPRItem = [];

for(let i=0; i<this.digitalAPR.length; i++){
    let newItem = {};
    newItem.Drawdown_Amount__c = this.digitalAPR[i]['Drawdown_Amount__c'];
    newItem.PMT_Digital_APR_Item__c = this.digitalAPR[i]['PMT_Digital_APR_Item__c'];
    listAPRItem.push(newItem);
}

handleCreateBusinessCase({recordId: this.recordId, jsonData: JSON.stringify(recordObj), untypedListAPR: listAPRItem, untypedListFiles: listFile, isDraft: isDraft})
.then(result => {
    console.log('handleCreateBusinessCase success');
    console.log(result);

    this.recordId = result;


What type of variable is digitalAPR?  Please edit your question to include this information. Also, don't paste screenshots of code.  Include the actual code with comments to call out important information such as where the code is stopping.

You first state the code stops at the line with the Apex call. Then you state at line 933 (which doesn't have an Apex call). What do you mean by the code stopped at that line, but you removed it, anyway? Your text could be clearer.

@NickC digitalAPR is an Array, I have updated the question.

@FelixvanHove I added line 933 just to debug what's inside the variable, but if I removed line 933, the code just stop at line 936 upon calling the handleCreateBusinessCase, the code execution just stop before call the apex yet.

Any solution to the question should be placed in the Answer section. This lets people looking for an answer similar to your question know that there's an answer. You are allowed (and encouraged) to answer your own question, and you can even accept your answer after a short wait period.
